# Show the ideal $I=(x^{2}-y,z-1)$ is prime in $K[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> I am tasked to show that the ideal $I=(x^{2}-y,z-1)\subset K[x,y,z]$ is it's own radical where $K$ is an algebraically closed field.

I tried to proceed in the obvious fashion.

Let $\varphi:K[x,y,z]\rightarrow K[x]$ be evaluation $f(x,y,z)\mapsto f(x,x^{2},1)$. It is trivial to show that $I\subset\ker\varphi$ but the other inclusion is not so trivial. This is what I've tried. Write $f(x,y,z)$ as a polynomial in $z$, $f(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=0}^{N}f_{i}(x,y)z^{i}$. Then $f(x,x^{2},1)=\sum_{i=0}^{N}f_{i}(x,x^{2})=0$. From here I am stuck because we have no idea how to show each $f_{i}(x,y)$ is divisible by $x^{2}-y$.

Another approach that I tried to take was to show that $I$ is its own radical by element argument but that failed miserably.

I would like to show this without the use of Groebner basis or multinomial long division. The reason being this is one of the exercises in Hartshorne and he doesn't touch on those things at all. This is not homework to be graded just cultural enrichment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find Gröbner bases more culturally enriching than anything in Chapter 1 of Hartshorne. :P

Comment: To show that $\ker\varphi\subseteq I$, you may start with an $i\in \ker\varphi$, and then successively reduce $i$ modulo $I$ first by getting rid of all $z$'s (that's what you have the $z-1$ for) and then by getting rid of all powers of $x$ with exponent greater than $1$ (using $x^2-y$). You obtain a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ only which has $x$ at most in power $1$. From here it is easy.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Dear darij, It's probably easier to replace all powers of $y$ by powers of $x$, so you end up with a polynomial just in $x$. (Not that it makes so much difference.) Regards,

Comment: @darij grinberg your method proved fruitful. Just needed to be more hard nosed about it.

Answer (score 5):

Quotient out by $I$ precisely means that you can replace $z$ by $1$ and $y$ by $x^2$, so the inclusion $k[x] \subset k[x,y,z]$ induces an isomorphism
$k[x] \cong k[x,y,z]/I$.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal is prime if and only if $K[x,y,z]/I$ is a domain. We have $$ \frac{K[x,y,z]}{(x^2-y, z-1) } \cong \frac{ K[x,y] }{(y-x^2)}.$$ You will be done if you show that $y-x^2\in K[x,y]$ is irreducible.

---

Here is a proof of the isomorphism I claimed above.

Define $$\phi : K[x,y,z] \to \frac{K[x,y]}{(y-x^2)}$$ by the mapping $p(x,y,z) \mapsto p(x,y,1) + (y-x^2).$ By direct substitution, $z-1$ and $y-x^2$ are in $\ker \phi$ so $(z-1, y-x^2) \subseteq \ker \phi.$

Conversely, suppose $p(x,y,z) \in \ker \phi.$ Then $p(x,y,1) \in (y-x^2).$ To be explicit, $p(x,y,1) = g(x,y)(y-x^2)$ for some $g(x,y)\in K[x,y].$

Writing out $p(x,y,z) = \sum a_i b_j c_k x^i y^j z^k$ we have

$$ p(x,y,z) - p(x,y,1) = \sum a_i b_j c_k x^i y^j (z^k -1)$$

and since $z^k-1 = (z-1)(1+z+z^2+\cdots z^{k-1})$ we have $$p(x,y,z) - p(x,y,1) = (z-1)h(x,y,z)$$ for some $h\in K[x,y,z].$ Therefore, $$p(x,y,z) = g(x,y)(y-x^2) + (z-1)h(x,y,z),$$ i.e. $p(x,y,z) \in (y-x^2, z-1).$ Thus, $\ker \phi = (y-x^2, z-1)$ and the First Isomorphism Theorem gives us the isomorphism we are after.

Comment: Or just note that there is an isomorphism $K[x,y]/(y-x^2) \simeq K[x]$ by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,x^2)$.

Comment: The problem is showing that $$ \frac{K[x,y,z]}{(x^2-y, z-1) } \cong \frac{ K[x,y] }{(y-x^2)}$$ The rest is easy. Typically, no one in the world adresses the real problem. Applying the third isomorphism theorem is not as straightforward here as people seem to think.

Comment: @RomandadeGore I agree that maybe some of the intermediate steps would not be so obvious if you haven't practiced this before. I'll edit my post to fill in the details. I generally prefer arguments with explicit maps and the first isomorphism theorem over the third isomorphism theorem.